# How to check if the request field is empty in laravel controller?

Tags: laravel

I have a form input named 'min' And in my controller, I used validation numeric, the user must type only number in it and if the user left it empty the value of 'minimum' set to zero and post to my database

here's my controller :

```
 $rules = [
        'user_id' => '',
        'name' => 'required|max:255|min:2',
        'description' => 'required|min:10|max:1000',
        'price' => 'required|numeric',
        'min' => 'numeric',
    ];
    $errormessages = [
        'required' => ':attribute is required !',
        'max' => ':attribute max size exceded ',
        'min' => ':attribute is too short',
        'numeric' => ':attribute must be numeric',

    ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules, $errormessages);

$userproduct = new Userproduct();
    $userproduct->user_id = auth()->id();
    $userproduct->name = $request->name;
    $userproduct->description = $request->description;
    $userproduct->price = $request->price;
    if (!empty($request->input('min')))
    {
        $userproduct->min = $request->min;
    }
    else {
        $userproduct->min = 0;
    }
$userproduct->save();
    return redirect('/profile/products')->with('message', 'Added sucsessfuly');
```

I tried too many ways like:
 if ($request->has('min')
if ($request->filled('min')

But when I submit the form it gives me an error "The min must be numeric", it seems still posting null!

Please Help me to solve this

Comment: Use `nullable` rules for accept null string.

Comment: @Majid this simply means you are using <input type="text" /> to accept numeric in controller. This will not work, either you should change your form field type to "number" or change controller rules.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you need to add nullable to your validation rules

Like this:

```
$rules = [
    'min' => 'nullable|numeric',
];
```

Laravel automatically converts empty strings to `null` and `null` is not a numeric value

Now it should accept numeric values and an empty field

Comment: I don't want to be null! Please see my question again, I just want if the user left the field 'min' empty the value of 'minimum' set to zero and post to my database

Comment: It seems like you don't understand what your problem is. Just try it and check if it matches your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs `numeric` validation you need to update controller code :

Add `nullable` with `numeric`

```
$rules = [
   'user_id' => '',
    'name' => 'required|max:255|min:2',
    'description' => 'required|min:10|max:1000',
    'price' => 'required|numeric',
    'min' => 'numeric|nullable',
 ];
 $errormessages = [
    'required' => ':attribute is required !',
    'max' => ':attribute max size exceded ',
    'min' => ':attribute is too short',
    'numeric' => ':attribute must be numeric',
];

$this->validate($request, $rules, $errormessages);

$userproduct = new Userproduct();
$userproduct->user_id = auth()->id();
$userproduct->name = $request->name;
$userproduct->description = $request->description;
$userproduct->price = $request->price;

//Here you already wrote logic for set 0 value.
if (!empty($request->input('min'))){
    $userproduct->min = $request->min;
} else {
    $userproduct->min = 0;
}
$userproduct->save();
return redirect('/profile/products')->with('message', 'Added sucsessfuly');
```

Comment: I don't want to be null! Please see my question again, I just want if the user left the field 'min' empty the value of 'minimum' set to zero and post to my database

Comment: @MajidAdigozalpour No no, You understood wrong because `nullable` means when   `Validation` executes at that time null value accept and then in your controller you already wrote logic for `min` value set 0. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @MajidAdigozalpour I have tested and it is working fine in my laravel installation so please try it..

Answer (score 1):

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'user_id' => '',
            'name' => 'required|max:255|min:2',
            'description' => 'required|min:10|max:1000',
            'price' => 'required|numeric',
            'min' => 'nullable|numeric',
        ],[
        'required' => ':attribute is required !',
        'max' => ':attribute max size exceded ',
        'min' => ':attribute is too short',
        'numeric' => ':attribute must be numeric',

    ]);

if (!$validator->fails()) {

   $userproduct->min = isset($request->min)?$request->min:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In laravel -`>get()` method works

try this one

```
$request->get('min')
```

Comment: please explain more

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$rules = [
    'min' => 'nullable|numeric',
];
```

set zero(0) if empty just say:

```
$min = $request->input('min', 0) ; // in this case 0 is the default value
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work ! the form submitted but in my database the value of min is set to NULL!

Comment: The thing is the validation rule "nullable" allows the form to post empty data otherwise it will be an error. With that rule activiated you can check for an empty value.

Comment: If "nullable" is in your validation rules just do: $userproduct->min = is_null(request->min) ? 0 : $request->min;

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply check if the value is set and if not, set it to 0

```
$rules = [
   'user_id' => '',
    'name' => 'required|max:255|min:2',
    'description' => 'required|min:10|max:1000',
    'price' => 'required|numeric',
    'min' => 'numeric|nullable',
 ];
 $errormessages = [
    'required' => ':attribute is required !',
    'max' => ':attribute max size exceded ',
    'min' => ':attribute is too short',
    'numeric' => ':attribute must be numeric',
];

$this->validate($request, $rules, $errormessages);

$userproduct = new Userproduct();
$userproduct->user_id = auth()->id();
$userproduct->name = $request->name;
$userproduct->description = $request->description;
$userproduct->price = $request->price;
$userproduct->min = $request->min ?? '0'; 
//The value of the 'min' field will be use and if empty/null, it will be set to 0.
$userproduct->save();

return redirect('/profile/products')->with('message', 'Added sucsessfuly');
```